# How to link headerfile and sourcefile by C++

Tags: ros, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to divide programs into source files and header files in src folder.
What do I need to link the some code ? Do I need to edit CMakeLists.txt?

For example :ekf_localization
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/tree/kinetic-devel/src

There are many programs in src folder and they are capable of linking one another.
What do I need to link to some proglams such as them?

Please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242630/how-to-link-headerfile-and-sourcefile-by-c++/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For source code to find header files, the CMakeLists.txt needs to be changed.

For example if your package formate is

```
dummy_pkg/
   src/
   include/
   CmakeLists.txt
   package.xml
```

Then in your CMakeLists.txt, you need to add

```
include_directories(
  include
)
```

will include header files in the include/ directory. If you are looking for headers in other ros packages then also add `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` inside those brackets.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2016-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-09-03**:
Thank you so much !!